# How to replace the variable output string with awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an awk script that converts yaml to an html tables, which works as follows.

**YAML file content:**

```
- soft1:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip
- soft1_beta_ver:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip
- soft1_alpha_ver:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip
- soft2:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip
- soft2_beta_ver:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip
- soft2_alpha_ver:
    V1.0.1: http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip
    V1.0.2: http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip
    V1.0.3: http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip

< Omit more... >
```

**AWK script content:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

/^-/ {
    sub(/:$/,"")
    out = type = $NF
    sub(/_.*/,"",out)
    close(out)
    if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
        prtBeg()
    }
    next
}
{
    sub(/:$/,"",$1)
    prtElt("<tr>")
    prtElt("<td>" type "</td>")
    prtElt("<td>" $1 "</td>")
    prtElt("<td>" $2 "</td>")
    prtElt("</tr>")
}
END {
    for (out in seen) {
        prtEnd()
    }
}

function prtElt(str) {
    depth[out] += gsub("<[^/<>]+>","&",str)
    printf "%*s%s\n", (depth[out]-1)*4, "", str > out".html"
    depth[out] -= gsub("</[^<>]+>","&",str)
}

function prtBeg() {
    prtElt("<table>")
    prtElt("<thead>")
    prtElt("<tr>")
    prtElt("<th>type</th>")
    prtElt("<th>ver</th>")
    prtElt("<th>link</th>")
    prtElt("</tr>")
    prtElt("</thead>")
    prtElt("<tbody>")
}

function prtEnd() {
    prtElt("</tbody>")
    prtElt("</table>")
}
```

By using the `cat xxx.yml | awk -f xxx.awk` command, it will output to multiple files separately, and the content looks like this.

```
[root@localhost html]# ls
soft1.html  soft2.html  test.awk  test.yml

[root@localhost html]# cat soft1.html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>ver</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1</td>
            <td>V1.0.1</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1</td>
            <td>V1.0.2</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1</td>
            <td>V1.0.3</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_beta_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.1</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_beta_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.2</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_beta_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.3</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_alpha_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.1</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.1.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_alpha_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.2</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.2.zip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>soft1_alpha_ver</td>
            <td>V1.0.3</td>
            <td>http://example.com/v1.0.3.zip</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to replace the "`type`" string in the table with a custom string, such as `soft1` replaced by `Release version`, `soft1_beta_ver` replaced with `Beta version`, `soft1_alpha_ver` replaced with `Alpha version`.

How can I do this? Any help thank you in advance!

Comment: wrt `cat xxx.yml | awk -f xxx.awk` - no. `awk -f xxx.awk xxx.yml` as shown at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544988/133219. Google UUOC.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank for your correction. In the previous question, because the reply has a word limit, so I created a new question. Can you answer this question? I am a newcomer to Linux, which is very difficult for me.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi How should I implement it in the awk script? Sorry, I only have basic Linux operations, which is very difficult for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the top:

```
BEGIN {
    map["soft1"] = "Release version"
    map["soft1_beta_ver"] = "Beta version"
    map["soft1_alpha_ver"] = "Alpha version"
}
```

and change these 2 lines:

```
out = type = $NF
sub(/_.*/,"",out)
```

to:

```
out = type = $NF
if (type in map) {
    type = map[type]
}
sub(/_.*/,"",out)
```

If you'll be doing any more text manipulation then get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to use awk.

Comment: There is a problem with the code, it will only replace the soft1 string, not the soft2.... Maybe it can be solved by ignoring the softx part of the regular expression, I will try to solve this problem, thank for your suggestion!

Comment: I am trying to add a regular expression to an array, which runs the prompt "`^ invalid char in expression`" error, which seems to be the wrong operation. After reading the [awk array document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_arrays.htm), it seems that I need to use "`Multi-Dimensional arrays`", I don't know how to achieve this. . .

Comment: I don't know what it is you're trying to do. As you can see in my answer the script I posted produces the output you said you wanted from the input you provided. Ask a new question with sample input/output that demonstrates your problem plus a description of that problem.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my description is not clear. The problem is this, the above code only replaces the `soft1` string, it will not work when reading text such as `soft2, `soft3`.

Comment: Hang on - you do understand you have to write the code to provide any additional mappings in the BEGIN section like I did for the 3 values you already told us in your question that you want mapped, right? Again, if you have a followup question then please post it as a new question with it's own concise, testable **and clear** sample input and expected output.